Jackson XmlMapper doesn't handle xml attribute correctly while deserialization
I'm trying to read xml from text, modify it, and print it. Creating an object from text to class is unavailable, since I have a class that extends Slf4jEventSender, and I'm trying to override getLogMessage method.
I'm using library jackson-dataformat-xml 2.11.1 to read xml from text to JsonNode.
Xml text:
<response>
    <innerField1 innerField1Attribute = "innerField1AttributeValue">
        <innerField2>
            <innerField3>innerField3Value</innerField3>
            <innerField4>innerField4Value</innerField4>
        </innerField2>
    </innerField1>
</response>

Reading JsonNode:
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(xmlText);

I may perform some edits here, but I wouldn't for now. And then jsonNode.toPrettyString() gives me innerField1Attribute as standalone attribute:
{
  "innerField1" : {
    "innerField1Attribute" : "innerField1AttributeValue",
    "innerField2" : {
      "innerField3" : "innerField3Value",
      "innerField4" : "innerField4Value"
    }
  }
}

I want to write xml with a tag innerField1Attribute inside innerField1, but since this attribute is already separated, the output is not what I want
xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode)

gives me
<ObjectNode>
    <innerField1>
        <innerField1Attribute>innerField1AttributeValue</innerField1Attribute>
        <innerField2>
            <innerField3>innerField3Value</innerField3>
            <innerField4>innerField4Value</innerField4>
        </innerField2>
    </innerField1>
</ObjectNode>

How to make innerField1Attribute stay at innerField1?

Looks like a limitation of XmlMapper since json is not xml-aware. JAXB might be needed to deserialize to a proper object having innerField1Attribute annotated as an attribute.

Per comment by @LMC,

"Attribute-ness" is not retained by JsonNode (no place for that, not xml aware)

An alternative approach with XmlMapper is to use custom types to use with readValue
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree(XML);
log.info("Pretty!");
log.info(node.toPrettyString());
log.info("XML again, from read tree!");
log.info(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(node));
Response response = xmlMapper.readValue(XML, Response.class);
log.info("XML again, from read value!");
log.info(result = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(response));

Response.java
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Response")
public class Response {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "innerField1")
    private InnerFieldOne innerFieldOne;

}

InnerFieldOne.java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class InnerFieldOne {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "innerField1Attribute")
    private String innerField1Attribute = "";

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "innerField2")
    private InnerFieldTwo innerFieldTwo;
}

InnerFieldTwo.java
@Data
public class InnerFieldTwo {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "innerField3")
    private PlainInnerField innerFieldThree;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "innerField4")
    private PlainInnerField innerFieldFour;

}

PlainInnerField.java
@Data
public class PlainInnerField {

    @JacksonXmlText
    private String value;

}

Sample Output
<ObjectNode>
  <innerField1>
    <innerField1Attribute>innerField1AttributeValue</innerField1Attribute>
    <innerField2>
      <innerField3>innerField3Value</innerField3>
      <innerField4>innerField4Value</innerField4>
    </innerField2>
  </innerField1>
</ObjectNode>



<Response>
  <innerField1 innerField1Attribute="innerField1AttributeValue">
    <innerField2>
      <innerField3>innerField3Value</innerField3>
      <innerField4>innerField4Value</innerField4>
    </innerField2>
  </innerField1>
</Response>

Note I've used lombok to avoid writing getters and setters.
Otherwise, again per comment, try jaxb
